# Checking a Spring Cloud CircuitBreakers status

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, circuit-breaker, resilience4j, spring-cloud-circuitbreaker

We're using [Spring cloud circuitbreaker](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker) to handle outages when making calls to an external service.
We also have a scheduled job which calls this service. I'd like to prevent the job from running if the circuitBreaker is open but I don't see any way of checking this as neither the CircuitBreaker (Resilience4JCircuitBeaker) or the CircuitBreakerFactory expose methods that allow this to be checked.
Is there another way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, you could use our Resilience4j [Spring Boot 2 starter](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3) and inject the CircuitBreakerRegistry into your class in order to check the status of a CircuitBreaker instance.
Our starter has a lot of other advantages like external configuration, annotation support, metrics, ...

Basically you can copy code snippets of our `CircuitBreakersHealthIndicator` class.

Comment: Many thanks @robert-winkler, that worked perfectly. I'll leave the question unanswered for now just in case anyone knows how to do it with Spring cloud circuitbreaker.